# Using multiple group by with count

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have this table:

```
+----+-------+------------+
| id |  name |       date |
+----+-------+------------+
| 1  | name1 | 01/01/2015 |
+----+-------+------------+
| 2  | name1 | 01/01/2015 |
+----+-------+------------+
| 3  | name1 | 01/02/2015 |
+----+-------+------------+
| 4  | name2 | 02/14/2015 |
+----+-------+------------+
| 5  | name2 | 02/16/2015 |
+----+-------+------------+
| 6  | name3 | 02/19/2015 |
+----+-------+------------+
```

And I need my query to return this:

```
+-------+---+
| name1 | 2 |
+-------+---+
| name2 | 2 |
+-------+---+
```

So basically I need the name and the count of occurences, but 1 day only counts once. Also I need names only if the count based on the previous criterion is above 1.
Tried like this but the result is not what I expect. I mean I checked the numbers 'manually' and

```
Select
  name, count(id)
From
  table
Group By
  name, date
Having
  Count(id) > 1
```

Comment: You want to count the number of distinct dates, and yet you use `count(id)` - why?

Comment: @jarlh Because 1 day counts once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select
  name, count(distinct date)
From
  table
Group By
  name
Having
  count(distinct date) > 1
```

Comment: How simple is that. I'm quite blind. Thank you.